# Configure Multiple App in Padrino with each having different Database and ORM Mapper

Tags: database, padrino, subapplication, gemfile

How to configure Multiple Applications in Padrino with each having different Database and ORM Mapper?
I referred to this [link](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/09/the-how-and-why-of-bundler-groups/) have got the way to Maintain different Gemfilesfor each App with each having gems of Database they require. But how to do configuration for each Databasem, where I can manage each databases loginid and password, port, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `config/database.rb` you can set all dbs configurations.

Once you do that, supposing that each app have their own models you should be able to work without problems.

Comment: Padrino's .components file is made for single orm i.e. either mongoid or datamapper. So the Project having multiple orms can not use Model generators.